# Labelling panels in a three part table

Tags: labels

My table has 3 panels. Can I add a separate label for each of these panels? I have tried adding label along with panel name but it returns the table number upon referring

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Eh, please be advised that `threeparttable` is also the name of a LaTeX package https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable?lang=en which doesn't seem to describe what you are trying to ask about. As it stands it is hard to understand what you are asking about. It can be helpful if you show some code and/or annotated outputs to illustrate what you want to accomplish.